# Fullscreen view in watchOS with SwiftUI

Tags: watchkit, swiftui, watchos-6

I wan't to display a SwiftUI `View` as fullscreen in `watchOS` (without the Cancel/Back Button or Clock)

I've tried adding a `Sprite Kit Scene` to the view and also setting the `.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)` but I'm still able to hide them or put a view under the top bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless it's a game, it's not possible to strip out the space at the top, watchOS reserves it so that the time is always visible to the user.

Comment: In storyboard I can select "Fullscreen" for the watch. Is this just not possible in swiftUI right now?

Answer (score 6):

Turns out it does "work", even with SwiftUI:

Using Interface Builder:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/wkinterfaceskscene/configuring_a_watchkit_scene_in_a_storyboard

Using SwiftUI (watchOS 7):

```swift
@main
struct BitApp: App {
  @SceneBuilder var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
      ContentView()
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }

    WKNotificationScene(controller: NotificationController.self, category: "myCategory")
  }
}
```

Remove any `NavigationView` and use `edgesIgnoringSafeArea` and **it works!**

*Edit:* It won't remove the clock though, as it will be positioned in the corner in front of the SpriteKit scene.

Comment: With Interface Builder, that only works for SpriteKit or SceneKit, try it and take a look. I've edited my answer to reflect this.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.