# SwiftUI fullscreen on Apple Watch

Tags: swiftui, apple-watch, watchos

Is it possible to use full screen on Apple Watch (except the time display) using SwiftUI?

I have set `.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)` on various view and the result is the same. Top left corner is not usable. [image: Apple Watch display not full in screen]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fullscreen view in watchOS with SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58336885/fullscreen-view-in-watchos-with-swiftui)